# In a Java application is there a way to format/indent an XSLT document?

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have a web application written in Java that allows our development team to check in, tag and push to production XSLT documents.  I would ideally like to have a way to format/indent the XSLT documents when an XSLT document is checked in.  This is so I can then run a text document compare between the old and new XSLT so our team can have a quick "what has changed" between the new and old XSLT documents.  The challenge is finding a way in Java to format XSLT documents.  I know tools like Oxygen have formatters but this leaves it up to each team member to always format the document before checking it in.  It also requires each team member to format the XSLT documents the same way.

Comment: Neither in Java nor anywhere. By design of XSLT, some parts cannot be indented by an algorithm without changing what the XSLT does. Do demand that your teams keep indentation unmodified. Have them check before they push.

Comment: An XSLT document is an XML document. You can format/indent it the same way as you would any XML document.